# Can I call model in zend helper?

Tags: zend-framework, helper

Somebody tell me that in zend helper, can I call model ? And if it's possible, how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Its as simple as instantiating `$state = new Model_DbTable_User();`

simple search would lead to [zend view helpers](http://inchoo.net/zend/zend-framework-custom-view-helper/)